# How does dates handling using Excel scripting interface via BERT work?

Tags: r, excel, bert-toolkit

I am having trouble understanding of how dates are handled.

I understand that Excel handles dates differently from R.  I am fine with reading in a date as a numerical value via R functions.  For example, in a workbook sheet "Sheet1" cell A1 I can input a date (for example 11Apr2018) as either a number 43201, any date format such as 4/11/2018 or 11-Apr-18, or formatted as text.

In my functions.R script I can save a function:

```
test_date1 <- function(x){
    print(str(x))
    return(x)
}
```

When I call this function in excel `=R.test_date1(A1)`, R reads this as a numeric variable.  If I have a range of dates in A1:A2 and use above function then I get a vector of numbers.  I am happy with this and can convert to R dates using `as.Date(x, origin="1899-12-30", tz='UTC')`.

Now when I try to use scripting in BERT, I cannot read in dates when they are not formatted as values. For example, if cell A1 is formatted as a number I i execute below script:

```
test_value <- EXCEL$Application$get_Sheets()$get_Item('Sheet1')$get_Range('A1')$get_Value()
```

My `test_date1` variable hold a number and I again can convert to an R date.  But when A1 is formatted as a date in excel the same script returns a `NULL` value.

Ultimately I would like to be able to reference ranges in excel and use time series for ggplot2 plotting and for statistical analysis.  But I am having problems handling dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an omission, BERT is not handling it properly.

When using the COM interface, this is a `DATE` type (that's just an alias for `double`, so it's still just a number). It will get fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: Thank you.  Will keep an eye out for next release.